# KALI Image (with installed broadcoam drivers that work for macbook pro late 2013) for live usb usage

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, macintosh

Do you know if does exists a kali iso where bcm4360 drivers are pre installed for macbook usage? I installed the official iso from kali.org on my usb stick for live usb usage on my macbook pro. I had the problem that the wifi wasn't working. So I tried the many 'tutorials for fixing the wifi problem on mac like this [one](https://wiki.debian.org/wl#Broadcom_BCM4311.2C_BCM4312.2C_BCM4313.2C_BCM4321.2C_BCM4322.2C_BCM43224.2C_BCM43225.2C_BCM43227.2C_BCM43228_devices_.28wl.29)' but all of them didn't work since it gives me a fatal error when I type modprobe wl. So because of this I am searching for image where I don't need to do this procedure of installing bcm drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there isn't any! I've tried anything you can find around the net. I also emailed broadcom, I called Apple Inc, etc.

I recommend you use a WiFi dongle - for instance ALFA Dongles. That works great!

But if you are expert in kernel, you may want to write driver modules for your NIC.

Comment: @OrkunAtasoy My pleasure mate, I will keep you informed if I can find anything.